# Python Playground Error: Boids Interactive Click in MatlibPlot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have been using the python playground book as a way to learn some python. Came across the chapter on the code for Boids. It uses matlibplot to essentially plot circles "moving" in a flock with rules.

The issue I am having is the button_press_event portion. The purpose of the event is:
Left Click - add a boid at mouse location.
Right Click - Scatter current flock at mouse location.

However, when I do click on the plot I get an error. This doesn't crash the program and it pops up with this message:

```
>   File
> "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py",
> line 388, in process
>     proxy(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py",

> line 228, in __call__
>     return mtd(*args, **kwargs) TypeError: buttonPress() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'
```

From my understanding this means that it is not actually able to accept the event (left or right click) or the event is missing in the input.

What is causing this error? How can this be fixed? Thank you

This is the code from the chapter of the book (from github with the corrections):

```
"""
boids.py
Implementation of Craig Reynold's BOIDs
Author: Mahesh Venkitachalam
"""

import sys, argparse
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform, pdist, cdist
from numpy.linalg import norm

width, height = 640, 480

class Boids:
    """Class that represents boids simulation"""
    def __init__(self, N):
        # init position & veclocites
        self.pos = [width/2.0, height/2.0] + 10*np.random.rand(2*N).reshape(N, 2)
        # normalized random velocities
        angles = 2*math.pi*np.random.rand(N)
        self.vel = np.array(list(zip(np.sin(angles), np.cos(angles))))
        self.N = N
        # min dist of approach
        self.minDist = 25.0
        # max magnitude of velocities calculated by "rules"
        self.maxRuleVel = 0.03
        # max maginitude of final velocity
        self.maxVel = 2.0

    def tick(self, frameNum, pts, beak):
        """Update the simulation by one time step"""
        # get pairwise distances
        self.distMatrix = squareform(pdist(self.pos))
        # apply rules:
        self.vel += self.applyRules()
        self.limit(self.vel, self.maxVel)
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.applyBC()
        # update data
        pts.set_data(self.pos.reshape(2*self.N)[::2],
                     self.pos.reshape(2*self.N)[1::2])
        vec = self.pos + 10*self.vel/self.maxVel
        beak.set_data(vec.reshape(2*self.N)[::2],
                      vec.reshape(2*self.N)[1::2])

    def limitVec(self, vec, maxVal):
        """Limit magnitude of 2D Vector"""
        mag = norm(vec)
        if mag > maxVal:
            vec[0], vec[1] = vec[0]*maxVal/mag, vec[1]*maxVal/mag

    def limit(self, X, maxVal):
        """Limit magnitide of 2D vectors in array X to maxValue"""
        for vec in X:
            self.limitVec(vec, maxVal)

    def applyBC(self):
        """apply boundary conditions"""
        deltaR = 2.0
        for coord in self.pos:
            if coord[0] > width + deltaR:
                coord[0] = - deltaR
            if coord[0] < - deltaR:
                coord[0] = width + deltaR
            if coord[1] > height + deltaR:
                coord[1] = - deltaR
            if coord[1] < - deltaR:
                coord[1] = height + deltaR

    def applyRules(self):
        # apply rule #1 - Separation
        D = self.distMatrix < 25.0
        vel = self.pos*D.sum(axis=1).reshape(self.N, 1) - D.dot(self.pos)
        self.limit(vel, self.maxRuleVel)

        # different distance threshold
        D = self.distMatrix < 50.0

        # apply rule #2 - Alignment
        vel2 = D.dot(self.vel)
        self.limit(vel2, self.maxRuleVel)
        vel += vel2

        # apply rule #3 - Cohesion
        vel3 = D.dot(self.pos) - self.pos
        self.limit(vel3, self.maxRuleVel)
        vel += vel3

        return vel

    def buttonPress(self, event):
        """event handler for matplotlib button presses"""
        # left click - add a boid
        if event.button == 1:
            self.pos = np.concatenate((self.pos,
                                       np.array([[event.xdata, event.ydata]])),
                                      axis=0)
            # random velocity
            angles = 2*math.pi*np.random.rand(1)
            v = np.array(list(zip(np.sin(angles), np.cos(angles))))
            self.vel = np.concatenate((self.vel, v), axis=0)
            self.N += 1
        # right click - scatter
        elif event.button == 3:
            # add scattering velocity
            self.vel += 0.1*(self.pos-np.array([[event.xdata, event.ydata]]))


def tick(frameNum, pts, beak, boids):
    #print frameNum
    """update function for animation"""
    boids.tick(frameNum, pts, beak)
    return pts, beak

# main fuction
def main():
    # use sys.arv if needed
    print('starting boids...')

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Implementing Craig Reynolds's Boids..")
    # add arguments
    parser.add_argument('--num-boids', dest='N', required=False)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # number of boids
    N = 100
    if args.N:
        N = int(args.N)


    # create boids
    boids = Boids(N)

    # setup plot
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, width), ylim=(0, height))

    pts, = ax.plot([], [], markersize=10,
                   c='k', marker='o', ls='None')
    beak, = ax.plot([],[], markersize=4,
                    c='r', marker='o', ls='None')
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, tick, fargs=(pts, beak, boids),
                                   interval=50)

    # add a "button press" event handler
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', Boids.buttonPress)

    plt.show()

# call main()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to write (notice the small "b" at `boids`):

`cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', boids.buttonPress)`

because `boids` is an instance of the class `Boids`, while `Boids.buttonPress()` is not a static function and thus cannot be called directly from the class `Boids`

Comment: Thank you so much! That was it. Appreciate the help.